# jQuery - pick out specific digit of an id

Tags: jquery

I have IDs in div-tags, that look like that:

```
    id="abc-0-0"
    id="abc-0-1"
    id="abc-0-2"
```

and so on.

I'd like to get the last numbers (here: 0, 1, 2.), to save them for example in a variable.

Can someone help out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same id is not good practice D:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
id='abc-0-0-0-0-0-9';
lastNum=id.substring(id.length-1, id.length);
/* some_string.substring(START, END);
returns a string from START to END position in some_string
where START and END are integers starting from 0 */
alert(lastNum);
```

Comment: thank you guys! i'll take this one. that's the best for my intention.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` and `splice` to get to the two numbers. eg.

```
"abc-0-1".split('-').splice(1)
// gives ["0", "1"]
```

Comment: **Bad Solution** this wont return an array of whole elements which answer the criteria - but only one ! the OP wants an array of whole matching elements !

Answer (score 0):

here  :

http://jsbin.com/abibek/edit#javascript,html

```
$("div").filter(

function ()
{
    return /^abc\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+$/.test($(this).attr("id"))
}).map(function ()
{
    return $(this).attr('id').split('-')[2]
}).get()
```